# Minecraft executing on a random enitity not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to set a stone block underneath a random armor stand, that is called disco stand. There are nine.

I put in this command:

```
/execute @r[name=DiscoStand] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone
```

... but it doesn't work. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

`@r`, by default, only selects players. To get it to select another entity, use the `type` argument:

```
/execute @r[name=DiscoStand,type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ stone
```